# HTTP_500 Error SAP Salesforce connectivity - SOAP

Tags: rest, soap, salesforce, wsdl, sap-basis

I am getting below error when connecting from Salesforce to SAP. Same configuration is working in production but throwing error in test environment.

> n0:Client Invalid WSDL access, no SOAP request expected An HTTP POST request with a SOAP request in the body was send to a WSDL URL. To call the web service use the service URL instead of the WSDL URL. To access the WSDL use an HTTP GET request or send the request with an empty HTTP body.
>
> Error executing cloud process [SAP_Create_Customer_Account] with id [28017]: HTTP_500 n0:Client Invalid WSDL access, no SOAP request expected

Comment: You are calling the WSDL instead of the webservice itself. Do you know the difference between a WSDL and a webservice?